# tensorflow: invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x00007f2fa8023940

Tags: c++, python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training inception model with TensorFlow from scratch following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception), this is my environment configuration：

- Tensorflow version: 0.11.0rc1 (compile from source)
- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 64bit
- model: models/inception

But after about 11500 steps got this error:

```
...
...
2016-11-03 22:37:06.142819: step 11540, loss = 9.38 (66.9 examples/sec; 0.957 sec/batch)
2016-11-03 22:37:15.753609: step 11550, loss = 9.22 (67.4 examples/sec; 0.950 sec/batch)
2016-11-03 22:37:25.332004: step 11560, loss = 9.51 (65.6 examples/sec; 0.975 sec/batch)
*** Error in `/home/software/anaconda2/bin/python': invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x00007f2fa8023940 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7d19d)[0x7f315d7b919d]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(+0x248ff48)[0x7f314baa2f48]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(+0x244520f)[0x7f314ba5820f]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(_ZN10tensorflow19LocalRendezvousImpl4SendERKNS_10Rendezvous9ParsedKeyERKNS1_4ArgsERKNS_6TensorEb+0xf9)[0x7f314bb9e7f9]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(_ZN10tensorflow22IntraProcessRendezvous4SendERKNS_10Rendezvous9ParsedKeyERKNS1_4ArgsERKNS_6TensorEb+0xb4)[0x7f314ba57b74]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(_ZN10tensorflow6SendOp7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextE+0x346)[0x7f314baa3736]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(+0x242ea59)[0x7f314ba41a59]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(+0x2422e30)[0x7f314ba35e30]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(_ZN5Eigen26NonBlockingThreadPoolTemplIN10tensorflow6thread16EigenEnvironmentEE10WorkerLoopEi+0x3c8)[0x7f314bc474a8]
/home/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so(_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN10tensorflow6thread16EigenEnvironment12CreateThreadESt8functionIS0_EEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data+0x22)[0x7f314bc46c72]
/home/software/anaconda2/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6(+0xb4870)[0x7f3149153870]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7df3)[0x7f315e20ddf3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f315d8321ad]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 34476856                           /home/software/anaconda2/bin/python2.7
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 34476856                           /home/software/anaconda2/bin/python2.7
0067e000-42ae4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
200000000-200100000 rw-s 1026d71000 00:05 221089                         /dev/nvidiactl
200100000-204100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
204100000-204200000 rw-s f70ee2000 00:05 221089                          /dev/nvidiactl
204200000-204300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
204300000-204400000 rw-s f75483000 00:05 221089                          /dev/nvidiactl
204400000-204500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
204500000-204600000 rw-s 1014d38000 00:05 221089                         /dev/nvidiactl
204600000-208600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
208600000-208700000 rw-s f7735a000 00:05 221089                          /dev/nvidiactl
208700000-208800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
208800000-208900000 rw-s f7777d000 00:05 221089                          /dev/nvidiactl
208900000-208a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
208a00000-208b00000 rw-s f77eaa000 00:05 221089                          /dev/nvidiactl
208b00000-20cb00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
...
...
```

Comment: Is this something you've seen more than once, or just a one-off error?

Comment: It happens every time. I have change the batch size from 256 to 64 and it also raise this error.

Comment: Can you boil it down to code you can post which reproduces the error?

Comment: I used the code of training inception model of tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/imagenet_train.py

Comment: If you're using the standard Inception model, my first instinct for this error would be memory corruption caused by hardware failure. Does it crash at step 11560 every time? Does it depend on the batch size?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that glibc is still not thread-safe, as the bug:
https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2014-0480.html